# Индикатор загрузки.

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт, работающий с большими таблицами. Им таблицы разбиваются на страницы. Переключение между страницами занимает некоторое, весьма заметное, время.
Хотел сделать, чтоб пользователю было ясно, что скрипт не завис а работает, нечто вроде индикатора загрузки.
такой вод код:

```
function repict(pg){
  $('body').append("<div class='wait'> Загрузка... </div>"); // показ индикатора
 /// сама функция обработки таблицы  
  $('div.wait').remove();                                    // удаление индикатора
}
```

он ожидаемо не работает, т.е. div не появляется. Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: странно:

`$('body').append($('<div/>').addClass('wait').text(' Загрузка... '));`

Comment: причем код, добавляемый через append, в коде страницы появляется. А в окне браузера нет.

Comment: может съезжает в неизвестном направлении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если попробывать вот так:

```
    function repict(pg){  
    $('body').append("<div class='wait'>
    Загрузка... </div>"); // показ
    индикатора

    setTimeout(function(){ 
   /// сама функция обработки таблицы    
    $('div.wait').remove();               
    // удаление индикатора 
  },1); 
}
```

Проблема может быть в том что всё идёт в одном потоке - мы добавили див, потом что то сделали, а потом прибили див, а потом уже обновили DOM модель для показа.

Comment: Да, я тоже примерно так думал. Но не додумался таймер использовать. Спасибо!